# What's Owin got to do with WCF?

Tags: web-services, wcf, owin

I have a WCF Service project. It builds with no error and runs in Visual Studio (2015). When I attempt to access the service page via the Browser, for example, http://localhost:59007/MyServiceEndpoint.svc it shows a yellow screen of death with references to Owin.

[image]

Hello ?! Whats OWIN got to do with it? I've used WCF before OWIN was invented, did not use OWIN before and don't intend to use now. I checked my Proj References, and there is no reference to Owin Dll's anywhere. What's going on?

Comment: Please add Startup1 file from this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana

Comment: @Sergey.. No. See part of my question where i said I've used WCF before OWIN was invented, did not use OWIN before and don't intend to use now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out even though I was not referencing OWIN anywhere in my WCF project, somehow the OWIN DLL's (Microsoft.Owin.dll, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll, Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll, Owin.dll, Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll) were present in the /bin of my WCF project.

I deleted all of them manually and now the yellow screen of death is gone !

Answer (score 0):

It may also work to add this to web.config's appSettings: